# How to read many files and export the numbers of rows in one table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Does anyone know how to initiate the loop to read all the files below and count the row in each table and export the number in one table? I use jupyter notebook to run the python (3.8) and use pandas to manipulate the data. I want to count how many tweets per day during certain period. I used twint to retrive the information and want to analyze the data.

```
df01 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-03.csv")
df02 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-04.csv")
df03 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-05.csv")
df04 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-06.csv")
df05 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-07.csv")
df06 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-08.csv")
df07 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-09.csv")
df08 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-10.csv")
df09 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-11.csv")
df10 = pd.read_csv("00_bitcoin_raw_2020-12.csv")

total_data_2020 = [len(df01),len(df02),len(df03),len(df04),len(df05),len(df06),len(df07),len(df08),len(df09),len(df10)]

df_2020 = pd.DataFrame(total_data_2020)

df_2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python 3.6+ you could use f-string [`formatting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) syntax to pad (`{i:02}`) the numbers generated with `range`. Optionally, use `header=None` to indicate that your data has no header, or, if does have, set the [`header`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) value accordingly to obtain the exact number of valid data rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

total_data_2020 = []
for i in range(3, 13):
    csv_name = f'00_bitcoin_raw_2020-{i:02}.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_name) # header=None
    total_data_2020.append((csv_name, len(df)))

df_2020 = pd.DataFrame(total_data_2020, columns=['csv_name', 'df_len'])
print(df_2020)
```

```py
                     csv_name  df_len
0  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-03.csv      13
1  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-04.csv      11
2  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-05.csv      11
3  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-06.csv      42
4  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-07.csv      23
5  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-08.csv      20
6  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-09.csv      11
7  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-10.csv      29
8  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-11.csv      28
9  00_bitcoin_raw_2020-12.csv      35
```